# How to translate facebook application name in action message?

Tags: api, action, translation, facebook-opengraph

In my case, user 'listens' to a track in my application, and the message about it sent to user's profile have the application name translated, as seen on screenshot (lower right corner): http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/7752/screenshot20121106at195.png
However, I cannot see where this translation is specified: it's not in the Localize tab of app settings, and it's not in the application translations list. I need to set the translation in prepositional case in Russian and cannot find where.

Comment: [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/internationalization/]

May be this will help.